# Trouble installing flutter on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I’ve been following a tutorial at [this address](https://mrgott.com/misc/39-how-to-install-flutter-on-a-mac-and-set-path-variable) but still can’t seem to run `flutter doctor` once I’ve finished and successfully run `echo $PATH`

The only reason I can think of is because I might have needed to initially change my directory to the flutter folder, and not the user folder but I doubt this would make any real difference.

I've contacted the author of this tutorial and he said that another user found this helpful;

`I managed to solve it myself after I began looking into 'fish'. Apparently I had to declare the path in "~/.config/fish/config.fish" rather than "~/.bash_profile" and then of course run "source ~/.config/fish/config.fish" rather than "source ~/.bash_profile"`

This is what my Terminal is looking like;

```
MacBook-Air:~ jake$ cd /users/jake/
MacBook-Air:jake jake$ touch .bash_profile
MacBook-Air:jake jake$ source $HOME/.bash_profile
MacBook-Air:jake jake$ echo $PATH
/flutter/bin:/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jake/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users      /jake/.composer/vendor/bin
MacBook-Air:jake jake$ flutter doctor
-bash: flutter: command not found
```

I'm expecting something like this; [image: expected result of flutter doctor]

Many thanks, Jake

Comment: Where is flutter located in your machine?.. (in my machine, it's in `~/Downloads/flutter`)

Comment: Mine’s located in ~Users/Jake/flutter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick fix:**

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Jake/flutter/bin
  flutter doctor
```

**Permanent fix:**

Assuming you are using `bash` shell,

- `cd $HOME`
- `touch .bashrc` if it is not there
- Add `Quick fix line 1` as last in `.bashrc` file
- Open new tab and check `flutter doctor`. It should work

Please lemme know if it didn't work

Comment: How do you want me to run this? Do you want me to run it in `sudo nano .bash_profile`? Also I don't know how to add it to `.bashrc/.zshrc/.fishrc` as I'm very new to this environment.

Comment: No, It says `= is not a valid identifier` and `/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jake/.composer/vendor/bin:/Users/Jake/flutter/bin': not a valid identifier`

Comment: Can u open new tab/window and try

Comment: Can u run this `echo $0` and tell the result

Comment: It says `-bash`

Comment: Do u have file named `.bashrc` at your home directory (/Users/Jake/)

Comment: No I don't, if I need to add this can you show me how?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the current status of your machine.. can u open new tab and `echo $PATH` and show the result here

Comment: Here's what I get `/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jake/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: Just to let you know, I purchased this machine just last Wednesday and haven't done anything like this in the past on this laptop other than install Git

Comment: I updated answer by removing spaces. Can u try the first two lines now

Comment: Okay this looks good, it's now downloading Dart SDK from flutter engine, I'll let you know how it goes when its finished

Comment: This worked great, thank you for your patience with me :)